# Access constant directly from Angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following lines:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.constant("const", {
   foo: "bar",
   test: "123"
});
```

I would like to now access the information in `constant` directly from the module `app`. Something like this didn't work:

```
console.log(app.constant.const.foo);
```

I know you can inject constants into controllers, services etc and access the information but for my purposes, I would like to access them straight off the module.

Is the only way to access a registered `constant` is to inject it into a controller/service/etc?

Comment: It seems that this is the only way (to inject), yes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming, somehow, you want an access to the `const` outside the angularjs environment.

Then you have to retrieve it from an `injector`, and there are two ways you can get the injector:

1. Get the current injector of a running angularjs application like this:

   ```
   var injector = angular.element(document).injector(); // assuming `ng-app` is on the document
   injector.get('const');
   ```
2. Create a new injector from existing modules:

   ```
   var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'app']); // note the 'ng' module is required this way
   injector.get('const');
   ```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ld7LLlr94N7PiqnxY5zH

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is very helpful, especially the second way illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to access the constant directly, you could do:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
var app.constants = {foo: "bar", test: "123"};
app.constant("const", app.constants);
console.log(app.constants.foo);
```

But, I don't see a real benefit ;)

Comment: Heh, that's my fault for not being clear. I am aware I can just attach the constant information on the module object itself as you illustrated. What I am wondering is if you can access the information without the: `var app.constants = {foo: "bar", test: "123"};` line first.

Comment: I gave my 2 cents on the comment on the very top ;) => you have to inject the constant.